# Why the main queue in iOS has to be a serial dispatch

Tags: objective-c

Why the main queue in iOS has to be a serial dispatch instead of a concurrent one? If it's the latter, wouldn't it be blocked anymore?

Comment: because there is only one main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the main *queue* is to provide a method for scheduling asynchronous work on the main *thread*.  If the queue was concurrent, not all work would be done on the main thread, and that would make the queue useless.

Comment: I thought concurrent means "do those thing at same time". I don't really understand why "not all work would be done on the main thread".